# How to force Windows 8.1 to use only part of the screen?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics

A white vertical stripe appeared on my laptop's screen today. Luckily it is on the side of the screen. My screen is 1366 x 768 I would like to force system to use only 1300 x 768(don't use 66 vertical lines on the left side).

Is this is manageable? The graphics card is the Intel HD4000.

Comment: You would need to shrink the image by double what you want to trim because it will automatically center it.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ok, that's fine but how to do it?

Comment: Say you need 60 off one side.  Look for the largest standard resolution that is no more than 1366-120, or 1246 in width.